# Trouble with Group By Sequence Numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am basically after sql that will do the following. I am after a sequential set of numbers in relation to when column B changes but keeping column ID in sequence
I have tried Dense Rank but it always throws out the sequence of the ID column which messes what I am after. Any ideas?

```
ID||A||B
01||T||1
02||T||1
03||T||0
04||T||0
05||T||1
06||T||1
07||T||1
08||T||0
09||T||1
10||T||1
11||T||0
```

INTO

```
ID||A||B||C
01||T||1||1
02||T||1||1
03||T||0||2
04||T||0||3
05||T||1||4
06||T||1||4
07||T||1||4
08||T||0||5
09||T||1||6
10||T||1||6
11||T||0||7
```

Comment: In the expected output, the row with ID = 4 has an incremented value in the column C. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
--#3: Running total of value changes
select id, a, b
    ,sum(has_changed) over (partition by A order by id
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) c
from
(
    --#2: Find rows where the value changed.
    select id, a, b
        ,case
            when b = lag(b) over (partition by A order by id) then 0
            else 1
        end has_changed    
    from
    (
        --#1: Test data
        select '01' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '02' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '03' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '04' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '05' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '06' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '07' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '08' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '09' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '10' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '11' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual
    ) test_data
)
order by id;
```

Results:

```
ID  A   B   C
01  T   1   1
02  T   1   1
03  T   0   2
04  T   0   2
05  T   1   3
06  T   1   3
07  T   1   3
08  T   0   4
09  T   1   5
10  T   1   5
11  T   0   6
```

Not exactly the same, although I think your example has an extra increment, as @Adam Hawkes pointed out.

---

**UPDATE**

This will generate your expected results:

```
--#3: Running total of value changes, or where the value is 0
select id, a, b
    ,sum(has_changed_or_0) over (partition by A order by id
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) c
from
(
    --#2: Find rows where the value changed, or where value is 0
    select id, a, b
        ,case
            when b = 0 then 1
            when b = lag(b) over (partition by A order by id) then 0
            else 1
        end has_changed_or_0
    from
    (
        --#1: Test data
        select '01' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '02' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '03' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '04' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '05' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '06' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '07' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '08' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual union all
        select '09' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '10' ID, 'T' A, 1 B from dual union all
        select '11' ID, 'T' A, 0 B from dual
    ) test_data
)
order by id;
```

Comment: Many thanks to you both for your help in this, yes you are correct the reason for the increment is that anything with a zero should increment as per the example given. This reason is that any thing flagged as a 1 in column B defines those rows to be contiguous to each other. However when the row return to zero it should return to the sequence if you catch my drift. So if you have 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0 in column B it would read something like 1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9 in Column C but again ensuring the ID column is in order asc as well. jonearles has nearly got it!!